# Drawing a hollow asterisks square/rectangle from user input in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program which asks the user for the width and length dimensions of a square/rectangle and then draws it out using the # symbol. I've almost got it, except I can't quite seem to get the right side of the rectangle to print out right...
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class warmup3
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
    int width; 
    int length;

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How big should the width of the square be?");
    width = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("How big should the length of the square be?");
    length= sc.nextInt(); 

    {
    for (int y= 0; y < length; y++)
    {
      for (int x= 0; x < width; x++)
      { 
        if (x == 0 || y == 0)
        {
          System.out.print("#");
        }
        else if (x != width && y == length-1)
        {
          System.out.print("#");
        }
        else if (y != length && x == width-1)
        {
          System.out.print("#");
        }
        else
        {
           System.out.print("");
        }
      }
    System.out.println("");
    }
    }
  }
}
```

I know the problem is with the second else-if statement but I am unable to fix it...

I am unable to upload a picture of what this code prints out but basically it's an almost complete rectangle but with two rows of #s on the left side and none enclosing the right side (right side is open) (you should be able to see for yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually with the last `else` statement.  Instead of printing out "nothing" or `""` you need to print out a space `" "`.  So change the else statement to:

```
    else
    {
       System.out.print(" ");
    }
```

That way when the loop is currently not at any of the edges it will print out a space, allowing the last `else if` to be in the proper location when printing out the last `#`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate as 2 dimensional array with logical checks:

```
public static void rectOuter(int length, int width) {

    String printStr = "*";
    String seprator = " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)

            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == length - 1 || j == width - 1)
                System.out.print(printStr + seprator);
            else
                System.out.print(seprator + seprator);

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

PS: System.out.print to be replaced with StringBuilder