# How to draw the characters in Java

Tags: java, character, symbols

Program length and width of the rectangle to be printed with symbols
for example

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529763/drawing-a-hollow-asterisks-square-rectangle-from-user-input-in-java

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem by your logic. You can see the below source code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Piramd1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner conin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many lines=");
        int n = conin.nextInt();

        for (int r = 1; r <= n; r++) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= n; c++) {

                if (r == 1 || r == n || c == 1 || c == n) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate as 2 dimensional array with logical checks:

```
public static void rectOuter(int length, int width) {

    String printStr = "*";
    String seprator = " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)

            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == length - 1 || j == width - 1)
                System.out.print(printStr + seprator);
            else
                System.out.print(seprator + seprator);

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

PS: System.out.print to be replaced with StringBuilder