# Rectangle with Asterisks Java

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop, shapes

I want to draw a Rectangle using asterisks.
Actually i have started something but don't  know how to continue how to go backwards you can go down by using println but how to go up 
Any help will be nice

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shapes 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
         Scanner Read=new Scanner(System.in);

         int i;
         int j;
         int W;
         int L;

         System.out.println("Enter the Rectangle Width then Lenghts");

         W=Read.nextInt();
         L=Read.nextInt();

         for (i=0;i<W;i++)
         {
             System.out.println("*");
         }

         for (j=0;j<L;j++)
         {
             System.out.print("*");
         }
         System.out.println("");    
    }   
}
```

Comment: I dont know the answer to your question, and i am curious how to achieve it. But i looked up in google for a library which might do the job, i suppose you want to create something like a user interface with your efforts, right? Take a look at this java library available on maven called [lanterna](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/).

Comment: Typically, this type of problem is solved with **nested** loops: an outer loop for each row and an inner loop for each column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing a hollow asterisks square/rectangle from user input in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529763/drawing-a-hollow-asterisks-square-rectangle-from-user-input-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

I will give you an idea.

take a number n, the number of asterisks.

- Iteration 1: In the first line print n number of asterisks
- iteration 2: print one * in the left and n-2 spaces consecutively and one more * in the right
- iteration 3: same as iteration 2
- iteration 4: same as iteration 3
- iteration (n-1) : same as above
- iteration n: same as iteration 1

Only thing is you have to adjust for the newline spacings because the end result might not look like a rectangle despite of having equal number of asterisks.